# How to i return the value of a property if i dont know the propertyname at run-time?

Tags: c#, reflection

And let's assume for simplicity that the value of the property needs to always be returned as a string.

```
public string GetTheValueOfTheProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo,Object myObject){
       string propname = propertyInfo.Name;
       if (propName == "IsSelected"){
          return myObject.IsSelected.ToString();
       }
    //...
}
```

This works, but it doesn't work if I don't know the name of the property. How would I do that in that scenario ?

Comment: I need to return every value of every property, for example iteratevely, without actually use the syntax "return myObject.IsSelected.ToString();

Comment: You could use `GetProperties` on the `Type` object to get a list of all the properties - the specifics depend on how you're calling the method above (in your question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx

You can call `propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null);`.

You can convert to a `string` with `ToString()`, but you should check for `null` values first - otherwise you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyInfo object lets you invoke the property on the object:

```
object value = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(myObject, new object[] { });
```

Comment: Quick warning; That assumes the property is a `string` and will throw an exception if it's a different type

Comment: You are right, I misread the question - I thought properties were strings, not to be returned as strings.